# textarea enter submit form how to recive post form

Tags: jquery

> ```
> > I want recive message from post.asp how do it ?thk you..
> ```

```
<form name="message" action="">
<textarea type="text" id="usermsg"></textarea>
</form>
<div id="chatbox"></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
 $(function() {
   var firstname = $("#usermsg").val();
   $("#usermsg").keypress(function (e) {

     var  firstname = $("#usermsg").val();
     if(e.which == 13) {   

        //I want to recive message from this post... how do it..**
        //$.post("post.asp",{update2:firstname} , function(data),
        $("#chatbox").append($(this).val() + "<br/>");
        $(this).val("");
        e.preventDefault();
     }
   });
 });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend of using `ajax()`

Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "post.asp",
  data: { update2: firstname } //you can add more values in here if you need
  }).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

Done will be triggered when ajax() call is done.

If you need to check if this code is done as you wanted then you can have something like:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "post.asp",
      data: { update2: firstname }, //you can add more values in here if you need
      cache: false,
      success: function(response)
      {alert(response);}                                               
       }).done(function( msg ) {
      alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    });
```

EDIT:

If you only want to post then you could use something like:

```
$.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" }).done(function(data) {  alert("Data loaded: " + data);});
```

Comment: i want to enter submit function only ,if submit normal function i can do it

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, try to be more specific